# Вращение картинки по кругу на css

Tags: html, css, jquery, css3, анимация

Есть круглая растровая картинка.

```html
<img src="http://photoholic24.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/smile_b.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
```

Как  заставить её вращаться по кругу на одном месте  по часовой стрелке - в положении 180 градусов смайл становится перевернутым) желательно на `css`?

Comment: что значит _вращаться по кругу_?

Comment: @Grundy по часовой стрелке переворачиваться

Comment: на одном месте? просто крутиться?

Comment: @Grundy да все правильно как колесо на одном месте

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```css
img.rot {
  animation: 1s linear 0s normal none infinite running rot;
  -webkit-animation: 1s linear 0s normal none infinite running rot;
  width: 100px;
}
@keyframes rot {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rot {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="rot" src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/grinning-face-smile-emoji-happy-37705.png">
```

Анимация по шагам))

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    img.rot {
      animation: 3s ease-in 0s normal none infinite running rot;
      -webkit-animation: 1s linear 0s normal none infinite running rot;
      animation-timing-function: steps(8, end);
      width: 100px;
    }
    @keyframes rot {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes rot {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <img class="rot" src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/grinning-face-smile-emoji-happy-37705.png">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: да, вот так! супер! спасибо

Comment: именно так и устроена анимация у font-awesome

Comment: Подскажите , тут картинка крутиться слева направо , а как сделать наоборот ?
что бы изображение крутилось справа налево ?

Comment: @ArnoldжеFree поменять местами 0 и 360

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться свойством [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

Которому можно задать анимацию, описанную в [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), а так же настройки анимации: продолжительной одной итерации, задержка перед запуском, количество повторений и т.д.

```css
@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

img{
  animation: spin 5s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://photoholic24.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/smile_b.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
```

Comment: спасибо! единственное, что @Jean-Claude написал первым

Comment: @Вася, ага, я долго описание смотрел :) поэтому добавил его, чтобы было где дальше смотреть

Answer (score 2):

### Анимация вращения при наведении курсора

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/3DWAbmN.jpg" />
```